# Foreach Array Looping

Tags: php, html

by using PHP, I would like to get all the href and src in the image URL, where each img src will assign with each a href like this :

```
<a href="http://example.com/src/abc.png"><img src="http://example.com/res/bca.png"></a>
```

And this is the code that i already created.

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$tags_links = array();
$tags_img = array();


foreach ($links as $link)
{
    $tags_links []  = $link->getAttribute('href');
}
foreach ($images as $image) 
{
    $tags_img [] = $image->getAttribute('src');
echo "<a href =\"".$url .$link->getAttribute('href')."\"><img src=\"".$url.$image->getAttribute('src')."\">"; 
}
```

But what i get is the last html assign with each img src

```
<a href ="http:../port287.html"><img src=../port2.png">
```

Any suggestion on how can i assign it like

```
<a href ="http:../port2.html"><img src=../port2.png">
<a href ="http:../port3.html"><img src=../port3.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly... and its safe to assume the $html you are loading in has a 1 to 1 relation of `a` tags and `img` tags... this may work out better for you:

```
for ($n=0; $n < $links->length; $n++)
{
    $href = $links->item($n)->getAttribute('href');
    $src = $images->item($n)->getAttribute('src');
    echo '<a href="'. $url . $href .'"><img src="'. $url . $src .'"></a>'; 
}
```

This will only work if the `a` tags and `img` tags relate. Otherwise you will have some work to do to associate which `href` goes with which `src`.